# OpenJFX not getting installed correctly

Tags: 18.04, java, openjdk, javafx

I have installed Java from this command:

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea-8-plugin
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
sudo apt-get install openjfx
```

So I installed IcedTea, openJDK 8 and openJFX. For some reason when I install openJFX by running:

```
sudo apt-get install openjfx
```

It says that it is already installed, but it clearly is not as it is not under any directories under my Java installation. For some reason, it is located under Intellij at path:

```
/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/133/jre64/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar
```

This results in Intellij not being able to detect JavaFX. What is wrong here?